# Вертикальный свайп в UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swipe, ios10

Добавляю свайп в первую ячейку таблицы:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var swipeDownBlock: (() -> Void)?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        selectionStyle = .none

        configureSwipe()
    }

    private func configureSwipe() {
        let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleGesture(gesture:)))
        swipeDown.direction = .down
        contentView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
    }

    @objc private func handleGesture(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        if gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.down {
            swipeDownBlock?()
        }
    }

}
```

и он работает, если таблица без скролла. Как только появляется скролл, свайп перехватывается таблицей - т.к. ячейка первая, а свайп вниз и bounce = false, то таблица никуда не двигается, но появляется полоска скролла справа. Можно ли настроить, чтобы свайп срабатывал?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно добавить делегата:

```
swipeDown.delegate = self
```

и переопределить один из методов протокола UIGestureRecognizerDelegate:

```
override func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

теперь жест распознается ячейкой.